# BitmapImage does not contain a definition for AutoPlay

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to play an animated gif in my UWP app, however after following the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.autoplay.aspx)

I'm still getting the error.  I have Visual Studio 2015 with update 3.

Am I missing a reference?

[image]
[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'BitmapImage' does not contain a definition for
>   'AutoPlay' and no extension method 'AutoPlay' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'BitmapImage' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Like it says [in the table at the bottom of the documentation for BitmapImage.AutoPlay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.autoplay.aspx): "Requirements (Windows 10 device family): 
Universal, introduced version **10.0.14393.0**."

Comment: @RaymondChen  I thought I had this installed already. How do I check if is it present? This is the Windows SDK for anniversary update right?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I check if is it present?

You could use the methods in ApiInformation class to check at runtime, whether a class, method, property, event or API contract is supported by the current operating system.

> The ApiInformation class located in the Windows.Foundation.Metadata namespace contains several static methods (like IsApiContractPresent, IsEventPresent, and IsMethodPresent) which are used to query for APIs.

Please read [Dynamically detecting features with API contracts (10 by 10)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/#FeO88ycFdfgj9FX4.97) for more details.

> This is the Windows SDK for anniversary update right?

Yes. You could downlaod it form here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

At the same time, you need to retarget your project to "14393".
[image]